# Having trouble hovering and clicking button using Capybara and Xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to click a button using Capybara. I've tried all combinations I can think of but no luck. Trying to click on the 'delete' link. The delete link only shows up when you hover over the row in the table.

This is the HTML:

```
    <tbody>
    <tr class="even" id="informal_6">
     <td class="columnOrganizationNameColumnValue" id="informal_7">

       <div>
         <a id="showLink_0" title="Organization Details" class="viewLink">
           Institution / Automation
         </a>
       </div>

       <div class="gridMenuDescription">
          &nbsp;
       </div>

       <div class="gridMenu">
           <a id="gridMenuDirectLink_1" title="Edit Organization" class="gridMenuItem">
             edit
           </a>

           <a id="gridMenuDirectLink_2" class="gridMenuItem delete">
             delete
           </a>
       </div>
     </td>

      </tbody>
```

I'd like to note, that the "gridMenu" div, when you hover over it using Firebug it turns to:

```
       <div class="gridMenu hover gridMenuShow">
```

Some things I've tried, but no luck:

```
    find(:xpath, '//*[(@id = "gridMenuDirectLink_2")]').click

    find("#informal_6").find("#informal_7").find(".gridMenu.hover.gridMenuShow").find(".gridMenuItem.delete").click
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Xpath that you have mentioned is not a button it's a link.
Try this:

click_link 'delete'

Comment: Tried, didn't work, I should add that the delete link only shows up when you hover over the row in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a crazy amount of attempts trying different things I was able to get it to work with this code:

```
  find('#informal_6').hover.find('.gridMenu').hover.find('.gridMenuItem.delete').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to hover over the row.

> > page.driver.browser.mouse.move_to(page.driver.browser.find_element(:id=>"locator"))

Comment: I called a .text on that and I got all the text on the page, but not the 'delete' link/button...

Comment: Try to get the text on the page after you have hover over on that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

I have a calendar interface where AJAX edit & delete links appear only when you hover over each calendar entry. It's nice and compact, but I had trouble getting Capybara to click on those dynamically displayed elements, and using `.hover` on the parent element didn't seem to make a difference. So I tried a brute-force approach that is working nicely so far:

```
# Use Jquery to force display a hidden element. Useful for getting at links
# that are dynamically displayed.
# Call it like: js_show(".entry.scheduled[data-id=\"#{@da3.id}\"] .actions")
def js_show(selector)
  page.execute_script(" $('#{selector}').show(); ")
end

def js_hide(selector)
  page.execute_script(" $('#{selector}').hide(); ")
end
```

Now, when I need to click on an element that's only displayed on hover etc., I can call `js_show(".whatever.container.selector")` to force the links to display, then `page.find(...).click` works.